# How to make a container width bigger in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create an event for my button that is in in my AsideMenu component that take the current width and if it's equal to 5vw than it will make it to 10vw else it will put it at 5vw and it must overlap the div named home. This is the code:

Thank you

I know how to do it with it vanilla javascript but not in react

````
import React from 'react'
import AsideMenu from '../components/AsideMenu'
import './Home.css'

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='assemble'>
        <div >
            <AsideMenu />
        </div>
        <div className='home'>
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `useRef` hook and get the current width. [This video](https://youtu.be/t2ypzz6gJm0) will explain it better for you. In case you get stuck, feel free to reach out. After using the `useRef`, you can then use a `ternery statement` in the return statement to actualize the code.